# может ли superclass наследовать от subclass?

Tags: python-3.x, классы, наследование

Добрый день.
Изучаю программирование на Python.
У меня есть один super-class и sub-classes.

И получается, что в моей программе класс более высокого уровня наследует метод класса более низкого уровня. Как такое возможно?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def say(self, stuff):
        return self.name + ' says: ' + stuff
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lecturer(Person):
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'I believe that ' + Person.say(self, stuff)

class Professor(Lecturer):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)

class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
    def lecture (self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + Lecturer.lecture (self, stuff)




e = Person('eric')
le = Lecturer('eric')
pe = Professor('eric')
ae = ArrogantProfessor('eric')

print(ae.say('the sky is blue'))
```

После запуска программы в IDE, получаю:

```
   ...jects/First_proj./arrogant_class.py
eric says: It is obvious that I believe that eric says: the sky is blue

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Класс Professor использует метод класса ArrogantProfessor? Или как называется это явление?

Comment: Считайте что наследование -- это получение свойств и методов класса-предка (супер класса), а если наследник у себя реализует такие же методы, что и у предка, то они подменяются, у вас такой метод это `lecture`. Кст, `Lecturer.lecture (self, stuff)` можно заменить на `super().lecture(stuff)`, т.е. вызов родительского метода

Answer (score 2):

`ae.say()` вызывает `Professor.say` метод (так как `ArrogantProfessor` наследует от `Professor` и `say` метод не переопределён в `ArrogantProfessor`) и передаёт `ae` как `self`, поэтому `self.lecture()` вызов `ArrogantProfessor.lecture` использует.

Чтобы посмотреть дерево наследования, можно `inspect` модуль использовать:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getclasstree(inspect.getmro(ArrogantProfessor))
[(<class 'object'>, ()),
 [(<class '__main__.Person'>, (<class 'object'>,)),
  [(<class '__main__.Lecturer'>, (<class '__main__.Person'>,)),
   [(<class '__main__.Professor'>, (<class '__main__.Lecturer'>,)),
    [(<class '__main__.ArrogantProfessor'>,
      (<class '__main__.Professor'>,))]]]]]
```

Вывод показывает, цепочку наследования:

```
ArrogantProfessor -> Professor -> Lecturer -> Person -> object
```

Видно, что Professor НЕ наследует от ArrogantProfessor.

---

Напрямую цикл наследования нельзя создать:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... class B(A):
...     pass
>>> A.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> A.__bases__ = (B,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a __bases__ item causes an inheritance cycle
a __bases__ item causes an inheritance cycle
```

Но можно создать виртуальный цикл наследования с помощью `abc.ABCMeta`:

```
>>> import abc
>>> class A:
...     pass

>>> class B(A, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
...     @classmethod
...     def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
...         return True  # everything is a subclass

>>> issubclass(B, A)
True
>>> issubclass(A, B)
True
```

В данном случае как B является подклассом A так и наоборот A является подклассом B (потому что любой класс является подклассом B --  `__subclasshook__` возвращает `True` для любого `subclass`).